# Generic type parameter marked as covariant with "out" keyword is not rendered correctly by doxygen

Tags: c#, doxygen

I have an interface with a type parameter marked as covariant with the "out" keyword:

```
    public interface IMultiLineResponseParser<out TResponse>
```

This is rendered by doxygen into:

IMultiLineResponseParser< out out TResponse > Interface Template

The "out" keyword is rendered two times. Can I prevent this with some configuration setting or is this a bug?

Comment: sounds buggy to me

Comment: Yeah of course. I just reported it as [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=789089).